# Sparse matrix compression with fast access time

Tags: c#, compression, lex

I'm writing a lexer generator as a spare time project, and I'm wondering about how to go about table compression. The tables in question are 2D arrays of `short` and very sparse. They are always 256 characters in one dimension. The other dimension is varying in size according to the number of states in the lexer.

The basic requirements of the compression is that

- The data should be accessible without decompressing the full data set. And accessible in constant O(1) time.
- Reasonably fast to compute the compressed table.

I understand the row displacement method, which is what I currently have implemented. It might be my naive implementation, but what I have is horrendously slow to generate, although quite fast to access. I suppose I could make this go faster using some established algorithm for string searching such as one of the algorithms found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

I suppose an option would be to use a `Dictionary`, but that feels like cheating, and I would like the fast access times that I would be able to get if I use straight arrays with some established algorithm. Perhaps I'm worrying needlessly about this.

From what I can gather, flex does not use this algorithm for it's lexing tables. Instead it seems to use something called *row/column equivalence which* I haven't really been able to find any explanation for.

I would really like to know how this row/column equivalence algorithm that flex uses works, or if there is any other good option that I should consider for this task.

**Edit:** To clarify more about what this data actually is. It is state information for state transitions in the lexer. The data needs to be stored in a compressed format *in memory* since the state tables can potentially be huge. It's also from this memory that the actual values will be accessed directly, without decompressing the tables. I have a working solution using row displacement, but it's murderously slow to compute - in partial due to my silly implementation.

Perhaps [my implementation](http://pastebin.com/LrfX8cH8) of the row displacement method will make it clearer how this data is accessed. It's a bit verbose and I hope it's OK that I've put it on pastebin instead of here.

The data is very sparse. It is usually a big bunch of zeroes followed by a few shorts for each state. It would be trivial to for instance run-length encode it but it would spoil the 
linear access time.

**Flex** apparently has two pairs of tables, `base` and `default` for the first pair and `next` and `check` for the second pair. These tables seems to index one another in ways I don't understand. The dragon book attempts to explain this, but as is often the case with that tome of arcane knowledge what it says is lost on lesser minds such as mine.

Answer (score 2):

This paper, http://www.syst.cs.kumamoto-u.ac.jp/~masato/cgi-bin/rp/files/p606-tarjan.pdf, describes a method for compressing sparse tables, and might be of interest.

Are you tables known beforehand, and you just need an efficient way to store and access them?

I'm not really familiar with the problem domain, but if your table has a fix size along one axis (256), then would a array of size 256, where each element was a vector of variable length work? Do you want to be able to pick out an element given a (x,y) pair?

Another cool solution that I've always wanted to use for something is a perfect hash table, http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html, where you generate a hash function from your data, so you will get minimal space requirements, and O(1) lookups (ie no collisions).

None of these solutions employ any type of compression, tho, they just minimize the amount of space wasted..

Comment: Thanks! The tables are known beforehand. I need to pick out an element given x and y. Minimizing the space wasted is actually exactly what I want to do, it's just normally referred to as compression in litterature. I'm attracted by perfect hashing as well. Going to try it out! Also, hello old co-worker, never expected to see you :)

Comment: Erm, I should say the tables are not known compile time, they're known before the compression starts. I have the full uncompressed data ready for compression at hand before the actual work starts. Just to be clear

Comment: does anyone have a copy of this document: http://www.syst.cs.kumamoto-u.ac.jp/~masato/cgi-bin/rp/files/p606-tarjan.pdf?

Because it looks that I have exactly the same problem with my lexer.

Answer (score -1):

What's unclear is if your table has "sequence property" in one dimension or another.

Sequence property naturally happens in human speech, since a word is composed of many letters, and the sequence of letters is likely to appear later on. It's also very common in binary program, source code, etc.

On the other hand, sampled data, such as raw audio, seismic values, etc. do not advertise sequence property. Their data can still be compressed, but using another model (such as a simple "delta model" followed by "entropy").

If your data has "sequence property" in any of the 2 dimensions, then you can use common compression algorithm, which will give you both speed and reliability. You just need to provide it with an input which is "sequence friendly" (i.e. select your dimension).

If speed is a concern for you, you can have a look at this C# implementation of a fast compressor which is also a very fast decompressor : https://github.com/stangelandcl/LZ4Sharp

Comment: Thank you, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I will clarify my question further, I realize I was unclear about how the data is being accessed by the lexer algorithm